# Make nested divs look like columns in css

Tags: css

I have nested divs representing tree of life data, for example

```
<div>
    Hominidae
    <div>
        Pan
        <div>
            Chimpanzee
        </div>
        <div>
            Bonobo
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Homo
        <div>
            Sapiens
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make this look like a tree in columns ie.

```
Hominidae    Pan    Chimpanzee
                    Bonobo
             Homo   Sapiens
```

I envisioned several solutions, in particular, three real columns and a grid, but I have a feeling just a little bit of CSS would make this solution the more efficient, if only I were more competent in CSS. The other solutions each had the drawback of adding way more JS logic.

Comment: Why don't you use float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  background: #bbb;
}
div div{
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hominidae
  <div>Pan
    <div>Chimpanzee</div>
    <div>Bonobo</div>
  </div>
  <div>Homo
    <div>Sapiens</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All solutions were quite good, and I'm happy to see I was right it could be done with a little css. I chose this one mainly because it's the one I managed to adapt the quickest to my html. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `grid` for this

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

div>div {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hominidae
  <div>
    Pan
    <div>
      Chimpanzee
    </div>
    <div>
      Bonobo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Homo
    <div>
      Sapiens
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container1 {
  float:right; width: 100%
}
.container2 {
  float:right; width: 60%
}
.container3 {
  float:right; width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class ="container1">
Hominidae
  <div class ="container2">
  Pan
    <div class ="container3">
    Chimpanzee
    </div>
    <div class ="container3">
    Bonobo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="container2">
  Homo
    <div class ="container3">
    Sapiens
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
display:flex;    
    }
    
div div{
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Hominidae</div>
  <div>        
    <div>Pan</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Homo</div>            
  </div>
  <div>        
    <div>Chimpanzee</div>
    <div>Bonobo</div>
    <div>Sapiens</div>
  </div>
</div>
```